# Difference between $Aut_R(M)$ and $Aut(M)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $M$ be a free module of rank $n$ over ring $R$.
Then, $Aut_R(M)$ is group of all autmorphism $M→M$ as $R$ module.
$Aut(M)$ is group of all autmomorphisms $M→M$ as a group.

It is known that $Aut_R(M) \cong GL(n,R)$.

But after checking some examples, R=I think $Aut_R(M)$ is the same as $Aut(M)$, Which is bigger as a group ?

Comment: It's immediate that $ Aut_R(M) \subseteq Aut(M) $, since any $R$-linear map is $\mathbb{Z} $-linear

Comment: And actually it is easy to find examples where it is strictly bigger, for example $R=\mathbb {Q} $, $ n=1$

Comment: I think in your example, both group is $\Bbb{Q}^{ \times}$.

Comment: Yes, my bad, $R=\mathbb{R} $ should work.

Comment: Actually, $R=\mathbb{Q} [\pi] $ is even better example

Comment: @buoyant Thanks for updating your question promptly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\text{Aut}(M)$ will usually be strictly bigger. The simplest way to describe it in general is the following: $\text{End}(M) \cong M_n(\text{End}(R))$ where by $\text{End}(R)$ I mean the endomorphism ring of the underlying abelian group of $R$. This gives

$$\text{Aut}(M) \cong GL_n(\text{End}(R))$$

and this will usually strictly contain $GL_n(R)$. For example, if $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$ then $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}[i]^n) \cong GL_n(M_2(\mathbb{Z})) \cong GL_{2n}(\mathbb{Z})$, which strictly contains $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}[i])$.

If you only checked examples like $R = \mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$, these rings have the special property that $R \cong \text{End}(R)$ which is usually false. I believe the rings for which this is true are exactly the [solid rings](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/core+of+a+ring#solid_rings) but I'm actually not sure how to prove it.

**Edit:** I was wrong! Rings satisfying this property are apparently called [rigid rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5265) and there are strictly more of them than solid rings.

Comment: Ah, those solid rings that I wrote [my first MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/110443/27465) about, ten years ago tomorrow ...